# Pass test data to fixture in testcase

Tags: c++, boost

I have a C++ (C++17) Boost 1.75 test fw based project.

I would like to write data driven test, but I cannot pass the data itself to the test fixture. (the test data shall modify some environment conditions, so I would like to do it in the fixture)

The reference code snippet that I have tried to use: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/test_org_reference/test_org_boost_test_dataset_fixture.html

Is it feasible in Boost Unit test FW?